# Correctly declare static variables in JavaScript classes

Tags: javascript, class

In my code, I do the following (very simplified):

```
class AddOrSelectAddress {
    static body; // <-- Error

    static async open() {
        await $.get(basePath + 'Manage/AddOrSelectAddress', null, result => {
            this.body = document.createElement('div');
            this.body.innerHTML = result;
        });
        // ...
    }

    static someOtherMethod() {
        // do something with body
    }
}
```

My code works fine in Chrome. Firefox, though, complaints an error in the second line of code:

> SyntaxError: bad method definition

I'm relatively new to class-based JavaScript programming. What am I doing wrong here?

[Static variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript) doesn't really help me, because it mainly uses old syntax.

Comment: @Kevin.a the `static` keyword is valid in JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535631/static-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: @Kevin.a I oriented myself on this definition: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Klassen

Comment: see static in MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static . Note that it's for static _methods_ , not members

Comment: I'm not sure that static variables are allowed to be undefined though... doesn't this defeat the point of making it undefined? Can't you just have it as a property of the class instead? As in, put it in the constructor and just don't declare it on instantiating the class?

Comment: @Pac0 Could you please explain me, how to fix my code? Only the `open` method needs to be accessed from outside.

Comment: @AndréReichelt if you only need the `body` variable inside the `open` method, why don't you declare it inside the method?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley It's actually accessed from a few places and methods in my class. But never from outside of the class. I have no idea, how to declase a private static variable, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Static class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Public_static_fields) are a stage 3 proposal, meaning they're not yet an official part of the JavaScript language. (Stage 4 is the final stage.) You can read more about the proposal [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features) and the proposal process [here](https://tc39.es/process-document/).

Currently, Chrome (as of version 72) is the only browser that [supports](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-static_class_fields) static class fields.

To use this feature in other browsers you would need to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) with [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to transpile your code. If you're not already using Babel, however, this might be overkill.

Alternatively, you can assign a property to the class after initializing it. This isn't semantically identical, but works for your (and, indeed, most) use cases.

```js
class AddOrSelectAddress {
  // ...
}

AddOrSelectAddress.body = 'some initial value';
```

You can see this working in the below snippet.

```js
class AddOrSelectAddress {
  static changeBody(val) {
    this.body = val;
  }

  static someMethod() {
    console.log('in someMethod body is', this.body);
  }

  static someOtherMethod() {
    console.log('in someOtherMethod body is', this.body);
  }
}
AddOrSelectAddress.body = 'some initial value';

AddOrSelectAddress.someMethod();
AddOrSelectAddress.changeBody('some other value');
AddOrSelectAddress.someOtherMethod();
```

If you don't want to set an initial value for `body` then you could just omit the line (since accessing a nonexistent property of an object returns `undefined`), or you could explicitly set it to `undefined`.

Comment: @AndréReichelt Does what, specifically, work for static fields? The code above is basically equivalent to the static class field in your question. (I've edited it to match the names you used in your code.)

Comment: @AndréReichelt I have edited my answer to include a working snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods are perfectly fine to use. However static properties are a recent addition that dont work in all browsers yet. It works in Chrome but like you said not in firefox. Please take a look at this article as it backs up my answer : https://javascript.info/static-properties-methods. To fix your issue you could declare the variable inside your static method.

Comment: Do you know a workaround? Just imagine, that my `someOtherMethod()` methods needs to access `body` as well.

Comment: How would I declare a class-global variable inside the static method? Just by defining it, like `this.stuff = null;`?

Comment: @AndréReichelt sadly i dont have a workaround for this, but take a look at the answer of Jordan, he seems to have more knowledge on the matter

Comment: @AndréReichelt might be worth to take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012663/how-to-define-a-static-property-in-the-es6-classes

Comment: Seems a little bit hacky, but at least, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Thats how we solve things that aren't available yet , until they are hahah