# How can I declare a const string in my Stimulus JS controller?

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

I'm wanting to set a const variable for a CSS selector for my controller, instead of having it hard coded throughout my controller.  I had put the declaration in the initialize() of my controller, but I'm getting an error that the variable wasn't declared.  What's the correct way of doing this?

**Current Attempt**

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["form"]

  initialize() {
    const seasonInputSelector = "input[id$='_season']"
  }

  change(event) {
    // ...
    var yearNodes = this.formTarget.querySelectorAll(seasonInputSelector)
    // ...
  }

}
```

**Error:** *ReferenceError: seasonInputSelector is not defined*

Comment: You're declaring `seasonInputSelector ` as a **local** inside the `initialize` method. It doesn't exist outside of `initialize`. You need to move it to be a static class-level field (as your class is anonymous you can't do this) or a const in the module's scope.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a `const` variable in the module's root scope:

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

const seasonInputSelector = "input[id$='_season']";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["form"]

  initialize() {
  }

  change(event) {
    // ...
    var yearNodes = this.formTarget.querySelectorAll( seasonInputSelector );
    // ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative is to scope it inside your class

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["form"]
  seasonInputSelector = "input[id$='_season']";

  change(event) {
    // ...
    var yearNodes = this.formTarget.querySelectorAll( this.seasonInputSelector );
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript/TypeScript don't allow for `static` fields in classes though, so this will add `seasonInputSelector` as a JavaScript prototype/instance property so it will be in **every instance** - in this case you're probably fine, but if you'll be creating many instances of this class then it should be declared as a class-level immediately after the `class` definition: see @zagoa's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48012789/159145

Comment: Basically, on the line _after_ `class Controller`'s closing brace `}`, put `Controller.seasonInputSelector = "input[id$='_season']";` and change `this.seasonInputSelector` to `Controller.seasonInputSelector`